# How to hide border in swiftUI control?

Tags: layout, border, swiftui, picker

Is it possible to hide a SwiftUI picker border? Possibly it belongs t some sub-layer.

By border, I mean the thin grey lines as per the image below.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    @State private var selectedOption = "A"

    let options = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text(selectedOption)
            Picker(selection: self.$selectedOption, label: Text("Picker Name")) {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                    Text(option).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
                }
            }
        .labelsHidden()
            .frame(width : 100, height : 30 )
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These grey lines is 'selection indicator' and it seems that Apple has same approach for SwiftUI as for UIKit UIPickerView, ie. show always.

Here is from Apple UIPickerView doc:

"**Special Considerations**
On iOS 7 and later you cannot customzie the picker view’s selection indicator. The selection indicator is always shown, so setting this property to false has no effect."

So no "official" way to do this... with Picker itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .clear
```

and then return your view